# Create Unordered Associative Container of Armadillo Vector

Tags: c++, stl, armadillo

I'm trying to create an std::unordered_set of Armadillo objects, e.g.

```
std::unordered_set<arma::vec2> my_set;
```

On compilation, the following code spits out about 60+ lines of error, I think the error has to do with vec2 not having a hash function.  I tried with both clang 3.5 and gcc 4.8.2.

```cpp
#include <unordered_set>
#include <armadillo>

bool operator==(arma::vec2 r, arma::vec2 l) {
    for (size_t i=0; i<r.size(); ++i)
        if (r[i]!=l[i]) return false;
    return true;
}

struct vec2Hash {
    size_t operator()(const arma::vec2& x) const {
        return std::hash<double>()(x[0]) ^ std::hash<double>()(x[1]);
    }
};


int main() {
    arma::vec2 a{1,2};
    std::unordered_set<arma::vec2,vec2Hash> t;
    t.insert(a);                                //This line doesn't compile.
    //unordered_set<vec2,vec2Hash> t({a});      //Neither would this line.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Armadillo defines an [operator==() function](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#operators) on Armadillo objects, so this might be interfering with your operator==().

Comment: Interesting.  Armadillo's definition returns a `uvec`/`umat`, whereas mine returns a `bool`.

Comment: Comparing floating point values (eg. float or double) for equality is not a good idea, as floating point values are at best an approximation. You explicitly need to take into account the accumulation of tiny imprecisions. It's safer to use "greater than" and "less than" comparisons.